# All possible scope options in Passport for Facebook and Google

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, passport-facebook, passport-google-oauth2

I am unable to locate all possible scope options in passport for facebook and google.
Could anyone mention all possible scope option/values that we could pass during authentication for facebook and google?

I need to use other scope options for facebook and google just like I am currently using 'email' scope values. Please mention all possible scope options for facebook and google seperately.

```
passport.authenticate(key, {scope: ['email']})(req, res, next);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the Passport documentation states, "Values for the scope option are provider-specific. Consult the provider's documentation for details regarding supported scopes." A list of facebook scope options can be found
[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions)
and google scopes
[here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#adexchangesellerv2.0)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may be confused by just *email* in `{scope: ['email']}`. This is the same as `{scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']}`.

Here are all the scopes for [google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#adexchangesellerv2.0). To access a scope that you want, find the url in the docs and set it when you are calling:

`passport.authenticate(key, {scope: ['YOUR DESIRED SCOPE URL']})(req, res, next);`

I haven't used passport for Facebook OAuth but it should be something similar.